# Filter pandas datafram by column, then by value within column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, filtering

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   COLOR   SHAPE   
0  red     square
1  red     oval
2  blue    circle
3  green   oval
4  red     square
5  purple  circle
6  red     triangle
7  violet  square
8  red     oval
9  yellow  circle
```

How can I filter a row (red) of a single column (color), so I get a new dataframe that looks like this?

```
   COLOR   SHAPE   
0  red     square
1  red     oval
4  red     square
6  red     triangle
8  red     oval
``
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.COLOR.eq('red')]`? Doesn't sound like you want a sort, just a filter.

Comment: That sounds about right. I just changed it. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, my comment should do it, there are some more options in the linked duplicate that might be helpful as well.